# How to indicate the dtype when using map on a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using map in a Pandas Series to apply a function that extracts any string representing a date or an empty string if there is no date in that string.

```
import pandas as pd
import dateparser

text_series = pd.Series(data={'label 1':'some text',
                              'label 2':'something happened on 2012-12-31',
                              'label 3':'2013-12-31'})

new_series = text_series.map(lambda x: dateparser.search.search_dates(x)[-1][1] if dateparser.search.search_dates(x) else "")
```

The code works as expected and I end with a new Series with datetime objects representing the dates in the strings.

```
label 1          NaT
label 2   2012-12-31
label 3   2013-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

My issue is that I get a warning because map infers datetime from the strings returned by the function and apparently that behaviour is deprecated and type should be indicated explicitely.

```
FutureWarning: Inferring datetime64[ns] from data containing strings is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To retain the old behavior explicitly pass Series(data, dtype={value.dtype})
```

How can I avoid this warning and avoid this code to stop working when the old behaviour stops working?

Comment: have you tried using `pd.to_datetime`? pandas native

Comment: I think this is an internal issue to pandas.

Comment: @AkmalSoliev pd.to_datetime directly on the text_series doesn't work because some of the strings are not only a date and have a date amongst other words. That's why I need something that searches for a date inside the string

Comment: @S3DEV thanks fixed it

Comment: @AlvaroAguilar have you tried using `.apply` instead of `.map`?

Comment: @AkmalSoliev Just tried it but no luck, I get the same warning. Thanks for replying and helping!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a different approach with regex

```py
import pandas as pd
import regex as re

text_series = pd.Series(data={'label 1':'some text',
                              'label 2':'something happened on 2012-12-31',
                              'label 3':'2013-12-31'})

def make_dt(row):
    x = re.search(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', row)
    if x:
        return pd.to_datetime(x.group(1))

new_series = text_series.apply(make_dt)
```

in case doesn't match the length: `r'(\d-\d-\d)'`

```py
output:
label 1          NaT
label 2   2012-12-31
label 3   2013-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: That's great, thanks!! The dates can be in different formats so I guess I will need to tweak the regular expression to allow for other ways to separate the numbers. But your approach is super helpful, I think I can totally get it done this way. Thanks!!

Comment: Happy that it helps! You can make it one liner, but then good luck debugging that